# Cassandra - Enabling Virtural Node causes new data unavailable from new DC

Tags: cassandra-2.0

Cassandra Version : 2.0.3

Environment : Linux OS, 2GB RAM, 180 GB Hard Disk, 
              DC1(Old) - 3 Nodes, 
              DC2(New) - 3 Nodes, 
              All machine have same configuration.

I followed this [link](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/configuration/configVnodesProduction_t.html) to enable virtual nodes in an existing data center.
Data is continuously written into Cassandra. After rebuilding nodes in the new data center, all nodes in the new data center receive data. As described in the link above, I start to migrate Cassandra from initial token to virtual nodes. But in between I found data (data which was added after rebuild) that is unavailable in the new data center. Data in the new data center is missing since the rebuild. After decommissioning nodes in the old data center, everything comes normal.

Comment: Did you change your keyspaces to use a `NetworkTopologyStrategy` and did you specify a replication factor for the new DC as well? What does the CREATE KEYSPACES from "DESC KEYSPACE <yourKs>" look like?

Comment: KEYSPACE "create keyspace mykeyspace with placement_strategy = 'NetworkTopologyStrategy' and strategy_options = {DC2 : 1, DC1 : 1}  and durable_writes = true;"